# Multi-display Nvidia issue, desktop sliding on secondary display - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I've been attempting to configure my laptop with a secondary display. Here's the details:

Laptop: Asus N56V
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
Primary display: 1080p laptop display
Secondary display: Samsung UE40H5000 1080p TV
On-board GPU: Intel HD 4000
Dedicated GPU: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] (rev a1)
Nvidia driver version: 340.76 from nvidia-340 (open-source)

I normally have Nvidia Prime set to use the Intel GPU and then use optirun to run applications on the Nvidia GPU. However, the Intel GPU doesn't appear to detect when the secondary display is plugged in (it isn't shown in the Screen Display settings). However, if I change Prime to use the Nvidia GPU, both displays are shown.

Mirroring the displays works fine (except for the occasional graphics freeze which I understand is a known bug with the Nvidia drivers). However, if I uncheck mirroring, I get some strange behaviour. At first glance, it appears to be correct - the TV shows the left desktop and the primary display the right desktop. Firstly, the primary display is actually frozen (I can see the cursor on it despite moving it on the other display). Secondly, when I try to move the cursor from the TV to the primary display, the desktop just *slides* on the TV - that is, it's like I'm pushing the viewport along with my cursor.

Here is what I get if I take a screenshot. I have added the red box to show you the area shown on my TV at the time. If I moved my cursor to the sides, this red box would slide along.

[image: Screenshot]

You can also see that nvidia-settings only shows the TV as a display and not the primary display.

Here's my current xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you're going to have a hard time getting answers for hybrid/optirun configs.  Everyone knows it's still super-buggy, so they typically don't buy the hardware.

Comment: @hbdgaf To be honest, I've had no issues with using optirun. It's only multi display via HDMI that's had any problems.

Comment: I wasn't saying it's universal bugs.  I was saying, everyone that uses it has some corner case bug just like this one, but different.

Answer (score 3):

Extremely likely that you're hooking up the TV to an HDMI port.  However, the NVidia is the only graphics adapter that can service the HDMI port internally in your PC as *the Intel can not*.

What I do before hooking up the TV is to disable the Intel in my BIOS, then the NVidia takes over for everything, and when I unhook it from the TV, I reboot again and go back to Hybrid mode...

**Crude, but effective!**

(And if you wouldn't believe me: you can also disable the NVidia in the BIOS and then the output of `lshw` will not show the HDMI port any more!  ;-)

Comment: You're right, I'm connecting by HDMI. Will disabling the Intel GPU likely fix this multi display issue?

Comment: Yes, but it will also consume more power, so that's why I use this system: I normally only use the Intel (without optirun) for day-to-day activities as going to AskUbuntu ;-) and reading mail etc, and only activate the NVidia when gaming or when watching movies on the TV...

Comment: @JosephMansfield: Is there anything wrong with my answer? I haven't seen any acceptance yet...  If it's a valid answer, please click the little grey check-mark under the "0".  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0 and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... :-(

Comment: Unfortunately I have no option to disable the Nvidia GPU in the BIOS (as far as I can tell). And nonetheless, I was under the impression that switching Nvidia Prime to the Nvidia GPU would run the entire environment on that card when I log back in, which gives me the ability to use the HDMI port but exhibits the problem described above. I've left the question unanswered because I'm hoping there might be another solution (if not now then at some point in the future). You were still, however, very helpful.

Comment: Chat??? AskUbuntu General room???

Comment: No time at the moment - working! :)

Comment: Try again tonight...  Type "@Fabby: I'm here for `http://askubuntu.com/questions/580443/multi-display-nvidia-issue-desktop-sliding-on-secondary-display-ubuntu-14-04/580450#580450`"

Comment: @JosephMansfield: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**